# How to check if key exists on mongoose document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `User Model` and recently added some key to it. This means that existing users will not have this key initially and new users do. Now I have a route where I want to check if the particular key exists on the user object so that I can add it if it returns false.

This is my route currently:

```
router.post("/new-application", verifyUser, (req, res) => {
  const { application } = req.body;
  User.findById(req.userId)
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.hasOwnProperty("applications")) {
        console.log("has applications");
      } else {
        console.log("has not applications");
        user["applications"] = initialApplications;
      }
      user.save().then((updatedUser) => {
        // console.log(updatedUser);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err fetching user: ", err);
      res.end();
    });
});
```

The problem is that `if (user.hasOwnProperty("applications"))` **always** returns false even after I added it to the user. I also tried `if("applications" in user)`. That also does not work.

So how can I check if a key or field exists on a Mongoose object.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of checking if the field exists or not can be done by `$exist`.

```
router.post("/new-application", verifyUser, (req, res) => {
  const { application } = req.body;
  User.findById({$and: [{_id: req.userId}, {applications: {$exists:false}}]})
    .then((user) => {
      // it will return the user only when  
     // applications doesn't exist
     
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err fetching user: ", err);
      res.end();
    });
});
```

Note: the reason your old user doesn't show the `applications` is they don't have it when you saved them and changing the model now won't add this property to old models. So, we can use the `$exists` operator to check it.

Comment: I am getting the error: `Error: Can't use $and`

Comment: I don't get why I just cant check the key like a normal object. `"applications" in userDeepClone` always returns true, even if the user doesn't have a applications key at all and `hasownproperty` always returns false. Even deepcloning the user object doesn't work at all.

Comment: There was syntax error,  check now

Comment: "In" - checks all the properties in the prototype chain, however, hasOwn only checks with the current model. It is quite possible that the chain might have a key with name "application"